# Vuejs computed, make it reactive

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, computed-properties, mutators

I need to save the computed value in my database, but it seems i cannot access it with the following example :

```js
computed: {
    total: {
        get: function() {
            return this.items.reduce(
                (acc, item) => acc + (item.price * item.quantity) * (1 - item.discount/100), 0
            )
        },
        set: function(newValue) {
            console.log(newValue);
            // this.tototata = newValue;
        }
    }
},
```

In the template, the computed value working well, but nothing appears in the console

I'm working with vue 2.6.11

Is this the best way to do this? Should i use methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the `computed setter` is called when manually setting the computed value. For example, the setter will be triggered if you do something like `this.total = newTotal`. In order to save the computed value in the database whenever it's updated, you might want to set up a watcher:

```
computed: {
  total: {
    get: function() {
      return this.items.reduce(
        (acc, item) => acc + (item.price * item.quantity) * (1 - item.discount / 100), 0
      )
    }
  }
},
watch: {
  total(newValue) {
    // Save to database
  }
}
```

You can read more about [Computed Setter](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter) here. Hope that this can help you solve the problem.

Comment: Thanks, i had to put the watcher outside of the computed function but it works great.

Comment: Yeah sorry, it was my mistake. It should be outside indeed. Glad it helps! I updated the answer btw.

Comment: Still wondering why the example on the doc doesn't work https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter

Comment: You can take a look at a small example I just wrote here: https://jsfiddle.net/k7zw3na5/6/.